# Issue with SharePoint masterpage and CssRegistration

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I created a stylesheet for an imagemap and wanted to add it to the masterpage. I did so by adding

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="/Style Library/CSS/imagemap.css" runat="server"/>
```

to the masterpage's header. I load a site but can't see the imagemap, I check the HTML source and when I use the link the stylesheet uses I can see it in a new browser window. I also tried with the full URL in the masterpage but still no imagemap.

I checked with FireBug and it loads the stylesheet but when I select it I get "no rules applied" (or similar) even though the stylesheet is not empty. I try with adding `after="corev4.css"`. Same result.

I then do:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/CSS/imagemap.css" />
```

instead of CssRegistration and it works fine. What am I doing wrong/missing with my first attempt above to load the css?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also have `<Sharepoint:CssLink runat="server" />`

Sharepoint:CssLink is the control that actually renders the styles. So, for every style defined by a SharePoint:CssRegistration, SharePoint:CssLink will process all of the runtime tokens like ~language and render the CSS files.

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing link.